# como insertar el Id de la Reunión en la tabla participantes estando en una sola pantalla

Tags: mysql, php5

tengo el siguiente problema... la pantalla principal se llama `"crear Reunión"` tengo los siguientes campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todos estos campos los inserto correctamente a su respectiva tabla `tbl_reunion` sin problemas, el problema viene a que en la misma pantalla esta la sección de de participantes a dicha Reunión, pero los participantes están en una tabla diferente en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y para poderlos guardar necesito el ID de la Reunión, que se esta guardando en este momento (en ningún momento se inserta el ID porque su ID es AUTO_INCREMENTABLE).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código que guardo en la BBDD la primera sección y con este no hay problema guarda corrrectamente los datos

```
<?php
include_once '../clases/conexionacta.php';
$agenda = $_POST['agenda'];
$asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
$enlace = $_POST['enlace'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$fecha_formateada = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha));
$horafinal = $_POST['horafinal'];
$horainicio = $_POST['horainicio'];
$lugar = $_POST['lugar'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

if ($_POST['reunion'] == 'nuevo') {
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_reunion (Id_Tipo, Id_Estado, Fecha, Nombre_Reunion, Lugar, Enlace, Hora_Inicio, Hora_Final, Asunto, Agenda_Propuesta) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("iissssssss", $tipo, $estado, $fecha_formateada, $nombre, $lugar, $enlace, $horainicio, $horafinal, $asunto, $agenda);
        $stmt->execute();
        $id_registro = $stmt->insert_id;
        if ($id_registro > 0) {
            $respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => 'exito',
                'id_registro' => $id_registro
            );
        } else {
            $respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => 'error'
            );
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    die(json_encode($respuesta));
}
```

como repito mi problema, es guardar los participantes, necesito el id de la Reunión que se esta guardando como podría hacer para extraer de cierto modo el ID de la Reunión

(las dos imágenes que puse de las pantallas son una sola)

Comment: Los participantes ¿están en otro formulario?. Intentaste hacer las inserciones de participantes después de obtener el insert_id y antes de enviar la respuesta?

Comment: estan en un mismo formulario

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu problema porque el id de la reunión recien insertada ya lo estás recuperando con $stmt->insert_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo debes usar una funcion o procedimiento en bases de datos donde estas procesando esa informacion para realizar el insert de la reunión en la tabla `tbl_reunion` es lo mas optimo y eficiente para trabajar con insert en multiples tablas al mismo tiempo, lo que debes hacer es declarar una variable en esa función tipo INT donde vas almacenar el `id_Reunion` el cual es AUTOINCREMENT, para luego por una variable especificia, que sea unica y no se repita buscar el `id_Reunion` recien creado, y lo almacenas en esa variable que creaste recien de tipo INT, con esto ya puede realizar el registro del participante con el ID. Te pongo un ejemplo de como deberia ser la funcion o precedimiento:

```
create procedure `Registro_Reunion_Participante` (IN Nombre VARCHAR, id_Tipo_Reunion INT, Id_Estado INT, Lugar VARCHAR, Fecha DATE, "ACA DEBES PONER TODAS LAS VARIABLES NECESARIAS PARA REALIZAR LOS INSERT O LAS VARIABLES QUE ENVIAS DESDE EL HTML") 
not deterministic
begin 
    //Esta es tu variable para guardar el id_Reunion    
    declare Id_Reunionn int;
    
    //Haces tu insert normal a la primer tabla
    INSERT INTO `tbl_reunion` (`id_Reunion`, `Id_Tipo`, `Id_Estado`, `Fecha`, `Nombre_Reunion`, `Lugar`, `Hora_Inicio`, `Hora_final`, `EL RESTO DE VARIABLE DE TU TABLA`) VALUES
    (default, id_Tipo_Reunion, Id_Estado, Fecha, Cantidad, "Las demas variables que ingresas en el procedimiento");

    //Ahora es donde realizas la consulta de tu id recien creada y la almacenas al mismo tiempo

    select tbl_reunion.id_Reunion into Id_Reunionn from tbl_reunion where tbl_reunion."COLUMNA" = "VARIBALE INGRESADA EN EL PROCEDIMIENTO";

    //Siguen los demas insert correspondiente de las otras tablas
            
end;
```

Yo te recomiendo que crees un campo o columna unica para tu tabla `tbl_reunion` tipo codio reunion que sea un VARCHAR pero sea un identificador unico que no se repita puede ser un random stream o un varchar que tu crees y se incremente con cada nueva reunion que desees ingresar tipo "RE-2020" y la siguiente sea "RE-2021", estos datos son unicos y te permitirán realizar la consulta de tu `id_Reunion`, puesto que puede pasar que si consultas el `id_Reunion` por nombre o fecha, el sistema te muestra el primer registro que cumpla con esas característica y tu registro entre en duplicidad y no registres exitosamente los datos como quieres.

Conclusion: recomiendo usar una funcion o procedimiento en base de datos, debes por recomendación agregar un campo único a la tabla `tbl_reunion` para que la consulta sea segura y eficiente, con esto tu proceso sera mucho mas rapido y seguro que si lo manejas desde el backend.

Espero entiendas todo lo que te pongo.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene de "óptimo y eficiente" un procedimiento almacenado?¿comparado con qué?

Comment: En que el procedimiento almacenado lo ejecuta el servidor, el cual tiene mas potencia y esta dedicado a eso, adicional la seguridad de la informacion no se trabaja desde el frontend o backend. Esto aligera la carga de tu pagina no se quedara procesado la informacion por un tiempo y después cargara la pagina. Inicialmente las personas creen que por ser un proceso pequeño no influye en el cargue de la pagina, pero cuando tienes múltiples usuarios ejecutando el mismo proceso tu pagina puede tardar demasiado en cargar, algo que no pasa si ejecutas el proceso desde el servidor. Buenas practicas.

Comment: El código PHP también lo ejecuta el servidor y las consultas INSERT las ejecuta un servidor de BBDD. Si se necesita un tratamiento masivo de datos quizás haya alguna ganancia pero en este caso no parece que la diferencia entre lanzar un puñado de INSERT y lanzar un puñado de INSERT encapsulados en un procedimiento sea muy significativa